# Parsing with NSXMLParser issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, parsing, nsxmlparser

I'm trying to parse the response from a web server.

My parser does as follows:

```
#import "XMLParser.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Child.h"

@implementation XMLParser

- (XMLParser *) initXMLParser {

     self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {
        appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"GetKidsResult"])
    {
        // initialize the array
        if(!appDelegate.children)
        {
            appDelegate.children = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        }

    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"a:KeyValueOfintKidf4KEWLbb"])
    {
        if(!aChild)
        {
        //Initialize the child.
            aChild = [[Child alloc] init];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Processing Element: %@", elementName);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string { 

    if(!currentElementValue) 
    {
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    }
    else
    {
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];
    }

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    //NSLog(@"El name: %@", elementName);

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"GetKidsResult"])

        NSLog(@"end of xml");
        return;    

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"a:KeyValueOfintKidf4KEWLbb"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Found end of child");

        [appDelegate.children addObject:aChild];

        aChild = nil;
    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"a:Key"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Found key");
    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"b:CheckedIn"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Found checkedIn");
    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"b:FirstName"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Found firstname");
    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"b:Gender"])
    {
        NSLog(@"found gender");
    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"b:Id"])
    {
        NSLog(@"found id");
    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"b:IsOnTour"])
    {
        NSLog(@"found isontour");

    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"b:LastName"])
    {
        NSLog(@"found lastname");
    }

    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"b:GroupName"])
    {
        NSLog(@"found groupname");
    }

    currentElementValue = nil;

}
@end
```

Right now I'm just trying to see if it finds the data... then I will save it afterwards...
But in my didEndElement, it doesn't seem to find anything other than

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"GetKidsResult"])
```

An example of my xml response:

```
            <a:KeyValueOfintKidf4KEWLbb>
            <a:Key>XXXXXXXX</a:Key>
            <a:Value xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DayCare.DB.DTO">
                <b:CheckedIn>false</b:CheckedIn>
                <b:FirstName>XXXXXXX</b:FirstName>
                <b:Gender>Male</b:Gender>
                <b:Id>XXXXXXXX</b:Id>
                <b:IsOnTour>false</b:IsOnTour>
                <b:LastName>XXXXXX</b:LastName>
                <b:Photo>XXXXXXXX</b:Photo>
                <b:GroupName>XXXXX</b:GroupName>
            </a:Value>
        </a:KeyValueOfintKidf4KEWLbb>
```

Any idea as to why it doesn't the other elements?
I've never done web services and such before, so the more simple the explanation, the better...

When I NSLog the element, I can see that it goes through the xml document properly

```
NSLog(@"Processing Element: %@", elementName);
```

Example:

```
Processing Element: a:KeyValueOfintKidf4KEWLbb
Processing Element: a:Key
Processing Element: a:Value
Processing Element: b:CheckedIn
Processing Element: b:FirstName
Processing Element: b:Gender
Processing Element: b:Id
Processing Element: b:IsOnTour
Processing Element: b:LastName
Processing Element: b:Photo
Processing Element: b:GroupName
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `didEndElement`, try changing this part:

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"GetKidsResult"])

    NSLog(@"end of xml");
    return;
```

to:

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"GetKidsResult"])
{
    NSLog(@"end of xml");
    return;  
}
```

Without putting those two statements after the `if` in a block, the `return` gets executed every time.

Comment: D'oh :D stupid mistake on my end... originally the NSLog wasn't there, so it wasn't a problem, but forgot to add the blocks after adding the NSLog... thanks :)

Comment: Will accept the answer in 5 minutes :) stackoverflow won't let me accept it earlier than that... but thanks!

Comment: That's why always enclosing blocks with "{" is a good pratice

Comment: Always always always use braces `{ ... }` for the if and else clauses, except if somebody is holding a gun to your head and even then it's better to hope it is not loaded.

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how to use the results :) I'm thinking something like [aChild setValue:currentElementValue forKey:@"firstName"];

Comment: That should work.  If firstName is a property in Child, you can also do aChild.firstName = currentElementValue.